# device is not apperaing in adb list even after installing the driver (Nexus s)

Tags: android, device, adb, device-driver

I am trying to do some android application using eclipse ,So i thought of using my Nexus s device .I downloaded the google driver from android SDK Manager and installed.

But still my device is not appearing in adb list.
i tried adb devices as well but i canot see my device.
I think the driver is not installed correctly . so i tried to uninstall the driver but device name is not apperaing in device manager as well.
I am
 sure that debugging mode is turned on my device.

Plese guide me to fix this issue...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have developer option on?

Comment: Yes i have and i turened on the debugging mode as well..

Comment: What is the OS of your desktop?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 64 bit...

Comment: I still use XP so cannot help you. But you can try to download the driver from Samsung

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Right Click Computer then Manage.
2. Expand Android phone at the top of the list.
3. Right click Android ADB Interface then Update Driver Software.
4. Browse my computer for driver software.
5. Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer.
6. Choose USB Composite Device then next.

If USB Composite Device doesn't show up then try browsing to the usb_driver folder in your android sdk directory for step 5 then try step 5 and 6 again.

And it works!